# Incorrect implementation of calloc() introduces division by zero and how to detect it via testing?

Tags: c, unit-testing, testing, malloc, undefined-behavior

I had an assignment in which I had to write my own calloc function (as well as a few other Libc functions), the only built-in functions allowed were `malloc()` and `free()`.

For context: the grading for my assignment is fully automated, some tests are run against my code on a server, and I get back either PASS or FAIL, if the code passed all tests or if it did not.
So what I'm trying to get at is I know my code didn't pass the requirements, but I don't know exactly why, it's just a guess.

Here is the code in question:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "libft.h"    // this is where ft_bzero is declared

void    *ft_calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
    void    *ptr;

    if (nmemb > (size_t)-1 / size && size)
        return (NULL);
    ptr = malloc(nmemb * size);
    if (!ptr)
        return (NULL);
    ft_bzero(ptr, nmemb * size);
    return (ptr);
}
```

I assume my mistake was that I mispositioned my conditional arguments and it should be like this instead:

```c
if (size && nmemb > (size_t)-1 / size)
```

so that we check if size is zero before dividing, which introduces undefined behaviour.

If that is indeed the error and there is nothing else troublesome in my code, how can you even detect this by running some tests?

I've tried calling the function with size 0 and it didn't crash my program, I've also tried compiling with `clang -fsanitize=integer-divide-by-zero` and it didn't produce any errors at runtime.

I am aware that by definition undefined behaviour is undefined so there is not really a way to detect it but it seems like whatever test was running on the backend server did.

Any ideas?

Comment: "how can you even detect this by running some tests"? Well, the server probably runs your code and tests calling ft_calloc with zero size, and then it crashes, and that is a failed test.

Comment: On some systems division by zero is triggering an exception, on some it isn't.

Comment: Well indeed, I'm sorry. I retried testing in complete isolation and I do get a `Floating point exception (core dumped)` error. There was probably something wrong in my testing environment that made it so the program didn't crash.

Comment: How about: `if ((size == 0) || (nmemb == 0)) return NULL; if (nmemb > ~((size_t) 0) / size) return NULL;`?

Comment: @CraigEstey what is `~((size_t) 0) `? Is it the same as SIZE_MAX?

Comment: @oguzismail In practice, yes. In `stdint.h`, `SIZE_MAX` is defined by a _decimal_ value. But that decimal value is [the equiv of]: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFUL. To me, the hex version is clearer, but it's not what `stdint.h` does. For `unsigned int`, `~0` would be 0xFFFFFFFF. By casting 0 to a given _type_, and the applying `~`, we invert all the zero bits into one bits (for the bit width of _type_). It's similar to what OP did as `-1` is all one bits but [IMO] its cleaner because its unsigned.

Comment: On x86_64 GCC 13.2 just optimizes the division away (even with -O0) and checks if multiplying size * nmemb results in an overflow instead. Due to the optimization a division by 0 cannot occur.

Comment: @Xypron Yes, that is exactly what happened on my my machine, I was compiling my tests with GCC, but my school uses Clang. As you said with GCC no exception is thrown, I talked with a colleague of mine and he suggested I use the `volatile` keyword on the size variable to bypass compiler optimization, but it didn't work. Do you reckon there is no way to make GCC behave like Clang in this case?